# Python Logging monitor through http server

Tags: python, http, sockets, logging

Is there any tools that catches python logging (socket or http) handlers' reports, and serves a http service so that I can check my logs through a http page?

Thanks

Finally... I found a working server that will do the job...

[LoggingWebMonitor](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577025-loggingwebmonitor-a-central-logging-server-and-mon/)

**UPDATE**

I found [Sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/sentry) on github, It seems more sophiscated and production-ready.

Comment: do you mean something like [LogRecordStreamHandler](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network)?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian yes, I have tried that one. that works for me, but I really want it to be accessed throuth http, so that log can be shared widely

Comment: Why don't you just log to a (safe) file and then point a regular webserver at that? Wouldn't that be easier and less bug prone?

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim : I intended to log multiple applications, on different server, I know if I only have one machine, one app, and logging is not really that intense(do not choke HDD), you are perfectly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many to tools to easily create simple RESTful HTTP webservices.  My favorite is [itty](https://github.com/toastdriven/itty).

```
from itty import get, run_itty
import glob, gzip, json, os, functools

def jsonify(origfunc):
    @functools.wraps(origfunc)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        result = origfunc(*args, **kwds)
        return json.dumps(result, indent=4)
    return wrapper

@get('/logs')
@jsonify
def list_logfiles(request):
    return glob.glob('/var/log/myserver/*.gz')

@get('/logs/(?P<name>\w+)')
def show_logfile(request, name):
    fullname = os.path.join('/var/log/myserver', name)
    with gzip.open(fullname, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()

run_itty(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but I can't do some heavy duty file logging in my server

Answer (score 1):

i recommend you bootle.py is a nice framework for this cases.

Here the link to project website: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/), simple to set up and has a nice interface. You'd listen to your logfiles or simply send logs to splunk. Even works remotly for logs in multiple servers. And you can do a lot more than just checking logs.